# Metadata not showing on opensea

Tags: solidity, nft

I have a problem with a simple nft program i did in order to learn more about ERC721.

this is the code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";

contract JonaNFT is ERC721URIStorage {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;
    uint256 private nftLimit = 4;

    constructor() ERC721("JonaNFT", "JNA") {}

    function mintJonaNft(string memory tokenURI) public returns (uint256) {
        require(_tokenIds.current() < 4, "All NFT minted");
        uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();
        _mint(msg.sender, newItemId);
        _setTokenURI(newItemId, tokenURI);
        _tokenIds.increment();
        return newItemId;
    }
}
```

I have the same problem for all 4 nfts: if i go to opensea i am not able to see the metadata even if i try to refresh it!

In my python testing program

```
def printNftInfo(tokenId):
    print(JonaNFT[-1].ownerOf(tokenId))
    print(JonaNFT[-1].tokenURI(tokenId))


def main():
    # deploy()
    # createAllNft()
    # createSingeNft(0)
    printNftInfo(0)
```

I can retrieve the uri of the nft of index 0 which is "https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmSFR5s4Gt8Njp6kLD1ifSjTWgzWSLaruyqdwfkD3x8vBR".
Do you see anythging wrong with the formatting?

Thank you and cheers from Italy.

Answer (score 0):

Your data seems to be valid.

If you are using Opensea's testnet the **issue might be with the page not your data at all**. Opensea often takes a lot of time to parse your data, even if you refresh it. I would therefore advise you to use Looksrare instead: https://goerli.looksrare.org/